# Get variables of SQL using regex

Tags: java, regex, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to use regex to get variable of part of SQL like:

```
from Person p group by p.lastname order by p.firstname
```

The regex expresission is

```
(\\s?((group\\s+by\\s+)(.*?\\s+))?(.*))
```

However, this will not works for  this SQL

```
from Person p group by p.lastname
```

My question is, does it exist a regex which could retrive variable of `GROUP BY`, for all kinds of SQL?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: That SQL does not contain any variables. It does contain object-identifiers, but an object-identifier is not a variable.

Comment: You cannot reliably and correctly parse SQL using Regular Expressions because SQL is not a “Regular Language”. Consider a SQL query that contains a string literal that itself contains SQL, for example, or nested subqueries in a CTE, and so on.

Comment: This is for Spring Data JPA. So it should works for all databases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regexp works for me.

```
\b(group\s+by\s+)(.+?)([\s;]|$)
```

I got rid of several unnecessary groups. Your version made the whole `GROUP BY xxx` expression optional, so it matches when that doesn't exist.

I use `\b` to match a word boundary at the beginning, instead of the optional whitespace.

I used `.+?` instead of `.*?` to match the identifer being grouped, so it will match at least one character.

Then I follow it with matching either whitespace, `;`, or the end of the string, so it will match if the `GROUP BY` clause is at the end of the query or followed by something else. I couldn't use `\b` here because the identifier might contain `.`, which is a word boundary.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/4d0uZj/2)

Comment: but the above grabs the `order by` section too, I think the asker only wants the `group by`s

Comment: No it doesn't, because `.+?` is non-greedy and stops at the first whitespace. See the updated demo.